# Disable append Configuration Name to Output Folder in vcproj

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

In a C# csproj project, AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath and AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath prevent msbuild from creating subfolders for target framework and runtime in the build output directory. However, the configuration name is still appended.

Is there a configuration option to prevent a separate subfolder for each configuration?

Answer (score 2):

So I figured out a solution to this. When editing the project settings in Visual Studio, it modifies the `<BaseOutputPath>` element in the XML project file. Simply change the element name to `<OutputPath>` instead, and it won't append the configuration name (and as you said, add `<AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>` and `<AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>false</AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>` to disable appending target framework and runtime identifier).

As an example, I have the following in a `<PropertyGroup>` in a C# project:

```
<OutputPath>$(SolutionDir)Build\$(Configuration)\Plugins</OutputPath> 
<AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
<AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>false</AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>
```

For a debug build, this will output the build files to `<SolutionDir>\Build\Debug\Plugins`.